# What does $\max(0\leq q \leq n-1)$ mean?

Tags: inequality, notation, algorithms, maxima-minima

I’m reading the C.L.R.S. algorithms book and came across this: $\max(0\leq q \leq n-1)$. I tried searching through the book to find out what it means, but couldn’t find anything. I understand what something like $\max(x, y, z)$ would mean, but I don’t know what these inequalities mean in this case. Any info on the matter would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What's the context? Is $q$ a natural number?

Comment: This particular exercise is asking me to show that the recurrence $T(n) = \max(0 \leq q \leq n-1) (T(q) + T(n-q-1)) + \theta (n)$ is the same as $\Omega (n^2)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you are reading a weirdly-typeset knockoff copy of the textbook, it should say
$$
     T(n) = \max\limits_{0 \le q \le n-1}(T(q) + T(n-q-1)) + \Theta(n)
$$
rather than $\max(0 \le q \le n-1)$.

The notation $\max\limits_{0 \le q \le n-1}(T(q) + T(n-q-1))$ means "the maximum value of $T(q) + T(n-q-1)$ over all $q$ such that $0 \le q \le n-1$". From context, we may guess that $q$ is an integer, though the notation is ambiguous on this point.

Comment: Thank you very much! I wasn't sure how to format the max function properly, but you seem to have it figured out. That is how it looks in the book. Thank you for the assistance!